How to check if the template node has hyphen when parsing go template?
{{- if .Tools }}
{{- end }}

{{ if .Tools }}
{{ end }}

import (
    "text/template"
    "text/template/parse"
)

t, err := template.New("dummy").Parse(string(templateText))

for _, tt := range t.Templates() {
    for _, n := range tt.Root.Nodes {
        switch n := n.(type) {
        case *parse.IfNode:
            fmt.Println(n.String())
        }
    }
}

This prints the same for both if conditions
{{if .Tools}}
{{end}}

Is it possible to figure out the first if and its end had a hyphen/dash?

Trimming happens during lexical analysis, parser never even sees it. Based on the documentation:

Trimming spaces.
If the action begins "{{- " rather than "{{", then all space/tab/newlines
preceding the action are trimmed; conversely if it ends " -}}" the
leading spaces are trimmed. This is done entirely in the lexer; the
parser never sees it happen.

So the answer is no, you cannot detect if the input is a trim by looking at the parse tree.
You can look at the Node.Pos, see the original location in the input text and try to parse it yourself.

ohhk. :(
I tried the following
{{- if .Tools }}
123
{{- end }}

{{ if or .Tools }}
ABC
{{ end }}

and
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", n.String())
It printed
"{{if .Tools}}\n123{{end}}"
and
"{{if or .Tools}}\nABC\n{{end}}"
Notice the \n in both cases. If the String() method is able to add \n in appropriate places, I am assuming there is something internally that is being managed?

I wouldn't trust n.String(), I doubt that's what's used for template output generation
